# How to convert to datetime even if the column contains strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column date as dtype object.

```
id           date         name
1           1/1/2020       A
2           2/1/2020       B
3           2/1/2020    
Total      3 Entries      2 Entries
```

I want to convert this date column to pd.datetime. But as it contains a Total it gives an error: `dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 3 Entries`

How can I tell pandas to change only the date format rows should be changed to datetime ? Actually I just want the month from that date to a new column. 
What are my alternatives to achieve this ?

desired result:

```
id           date         name          month
1           1/1/2020       A              1
2           2/1/2020       B              1
3           2/1/2020                      1
Total      3 Entries      2 Entries     Nan/0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors=coerce` will parse invalid dates & set to `NaT`.

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%d/%m/%Y", errors='coerce').dt.month

print(df['month'])
```

output,

```
      id       date       name  month
0      1   1/1/2020          A    1.0
1      2   2/1/2020          B    1.0
2      3   2/1/2020       None    1.0
3  Total  3 Entries  2 Entries    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in df['date']:
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(d)
```

Or, you could use .apply():

```
convert_to_datetime = lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d).month

df['date'].apply(convert_to_datetime)
```

The month will be of type float, so you might need to convert it to int.